# ActionScript 2.0 and ActionScript 3.0 project

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I have a new project I'm working on that will require a Flash application to load both AS2 SWF files and AS3 Flash files as well as FLV movies.  The new Flash application will control the loaded SWF files by moving to different frames within the main timeline.

I should be able to get the source for all the files that are loaded into the Flash piece, but I'm not positive that will always happen.  From what I have read is that you can create a bridge file in the AS2 files and use the local connection feature to control the loaded AS2 piece.

Is there a better way of approaching this so I don't need to use the bridge file, or am I forced to get the source files of the AS2 SWFs to control them within the main AS3 Flash piece.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

JumpEye Components.com Has A Good Free AS2 Bridge Available:

http://www.jumpeyecomponents.com/Flash-Components/Various/ActionScript-Bridge-91/

What can be done using ASB?

A. Use flash AS2.0 flash components in AS3.0 projects.

B. Use older AS2.0 widgets, flash files inside newer AS3.0 projects.

C. Use AS2.0 methods, functions or classes inside AS3.0 projects, call them and get returns back.

Technically: Load Macromedia/Adobe Flash AS2.0 projects (swf) inside Adobe Flash AS3.0 projects using ASB and communicate between them. Call functions, fire up events and get return variables using our ASB API.

Answer (score 1):

maybe a bit late. But just in case some else is looking for it. The easiest way to communicate AS2 with AS3 is by using LocalConnection, that's all. I hope it helps.